# flutter : how to check time with if statement when pressing button

Tags: flutter

hello iam new to flutter and making an eCommerce app and i want to check time , like if it is between 7 and 12 pm a dialog pops up , i know that is done with an if statement but how to implement the DateTime in the if statment
this is what i got so far but it's not working and i dont know why !

```
FlatButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      if(DateTime.now().hour >16 && DateTime.now().hour<0){
                        Dialog(
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0)),
                          //this right here
                          child: Container(
                            height: 200,
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                              child: Column(
                                mainAxisAlignment:
                                MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                crossAxisAlignment:
                                CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                children: [
                                  Row(
                                    mainAxisAlignment:
                                    MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      Text(
                                        'hello',
                                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
                      }
```

Comment: The hour can't be both >16 and <0!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DateTime.now()` will give you a `DateTime` object for the time in local time.  You can call `.hour` on that value to get the hour from 0 to 23. If it's >= 19, you're in your time window to do something different. So:

```
if (DateTime.now().hour >= 19) { pop up the dialog }
```

One thing to consider is if the user will be in a different timezone.  If so, you should use `DateTime.utc()` for UTC time, and make appropriate adjustments to the significant range of hours.

Comment: I have added my response as a comment. :)

Comment: how can i but it in range between , lets say 16 and 0

Comment: i have did this and passed on the time now it should work but is not ! 
if(DateTime.now().hour >=0)

Comment: hour will be 16 to 23 for all times from 4pm to midnight, so you just need to say >= 16.

Comment: And .hour >= 0 is true 24 hours a day!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229274/discussion-between-randal-schwartz-and-fahmi-sawalha).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a start of solution.

I created two dialogs, so that one will be shown wherever you are. Here, it's currently not between 7AM and 12PM.

[image]

- I used `TimeOfDay` that seems more adequate than `DateTime`
- I used `Future.microtask(() {})` in order to wait for the build to be finished before I show the dialog.
- I used `useEffect(() {}, [])` from [Flutter Hooks package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_hooks), so that the dialog is not shown at every rebuild of the Widget. Note, you may also achieve this with a `StatefulWidget` `initState()`.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_hooks/flutter_hooks.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: Scaffold(body: HomePage()),
    ),
  );
}

class HomePage extends HookWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    useEffect(() {
      Future.microtask(() {
        final now = TimeOfDay.now();
        if (now.hour >= 7 && now.hour <= 12) {
          showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
              title: Text('Hello!'),
              content: Text("It's currently between 7AM and 12PM."),
            ),
          );
        } else {
          showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
              title: Text('Hello!'),
              content: Text("It's currently NOT between 7AM and 12PM."),
            ),
          );
        }
      });
      return;
    }, []);
    return Container(color: Colors.green.shade200);
  }
}
```